# SocketIO is not emitting new incoming data frrom mongo to frontend using Flask

Tags: mongodb, flask, socket.io, pymongo

My code utilizes Change Streams to detect any newly inserted data in MongoDB. Subsequently, it is designed to emit this new data to the frontend using SocketIO.

Currently, the Flask code effectively detects changes or new data in MongoDB, and the data is visibly printed in the terminal. However, there is an issue where the detected data is not successfully emitted. Despite successful testing with a simple function that emits data, the specific reason for the failure to emit the detected data remains unclear.

I will appreciate any help or advice, I have spent multiple days with this issue.

Flask App:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from pymongo import MongoClient
from flask_socketio import SocketIO
from flask_cors import CORS
import threading

app = Flask(__name__)
socketio = SocketIO(app, cors_allowed_origins="http://127.0.0.1:5000")

# Replace the following line with your MongoDB Atlas connection string
client = MongoClient("mongodb+srv://code7lab:password@cluster0.jlosawe.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority")

# Access the 'test' database using dictionary-style notation
db = client['test']

# List collections in the current database
collections = db.list_collection_names()
print(f"Collections in {db.name}: {collections}")

collection = db.coordinates

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@socketio.on('connect')
def handle_connect():
    print('Client connected')

@socketio.on('disconnect')
def handle_disconnect():
    print('Client disconnected')

def watch_collection():
    print("Watching collection...")
    try:
        with collection.watch() as change_stream:
            for change in change_stream:
                print("Change detected:", change)

                if 'fullDocument' in change:
                    new_data = change['fullDocument']
                    new_data['_id'] = str(new_data['_id'])
                    print("New Data:", new_data)
                    socketio.emit('new_data', new_data)
                else:
                    print("Change event does not contain 'fullDocument'.")
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error in change stream:", e)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    thread = threading.Thread(target=watch_collection)
    thread.daemon = True
    thread.start()
    socketio.run(app, debug=True)
```

Simple Test working CODE:

```
def emit_data():
    count = 0
    while True:
        socketio.emit('new_data', {'count': count, 'message': 'Hello from server!'})
        count += 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    thread = threading.Thread(target=emit_data)
    thread.daemon = True
    thread.start()
    socketio.run(app, debug=True)
```

FrontEnd HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Socket.IO Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Socket.IO Example</h1>
    <ul id="data-list"></ul>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/4.0.1/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
            var socket = io.connect('http://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port);

            socket.on('connect', function () {
                console.log('Connected to server');
            });

            socket.on('new_data', function (data) {
                console.log('New data received:', data);

                var dataList = document.getElementById('data-list');
                dataList.innerHTML = ''; // Clear existing list

                var listItem = document.createElement('li');
                listItem.appendChild(document.createTextNode(JSON.stringify(data)));
                dataList.appendChild(listItem);
            });

            socket.on('disconnect', function () {
                console.log('Disconnected from server');
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```